# Snowflake: infer_schema function

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I'm trying out Snowflake's [infer_schema](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/infer_schema.html) function and I'm wondering if Snowflake infer_schema function gets metadata from the latest parquet file in S3 ?

Comment: More code to reproduce please?

Comment: Per the documentation, your file needs to be in either an internal or external stage, not just in an S3 bucket, and scans all files in all subdirectories of the specified location.  The results are based on all the files, not just the earliest or latest:  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/infer_schema.html#infer-schema

Answer (score 0):

[INFER_SCHEMA](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/infer_schema.html) function supports `FILES` parameter:

> ```
> INFER_SCHEMA(
>   LOCATION => '{ internalStage | externalStage }'
>   , FILE_FORMAT => '<file_format_name>'
>   , FILES => '<file_name>' [ , '<file_name>' ] [ , ... ]
>   , IGNORE_CASE => TRUE | FALSE
> )
> ```
>
> Options:
>
> ```
> FILES => '<file_name>' [ , '<file_name>' ] [ , ... ]
> ```
>
> Specifies a list of one or more files (separated by commas) in a set of staged files that contain semi-structured data. The files must already have been staged in either the Snowflake internal location or external location specified in the command. If any of the specified files cannot be found, the query will be aborted.

The file name of the newest file at stage could be found using [LIST](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/list.html) :

> Returns a list of files that have been staged (i.e. uploaded from a local file system or unloaded from a table) in one of the following Snowflake stages:

Pseudocode:

```
LIST @mystage/path1;

SET file_name = (SELECT s."name"
                 FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID())) s
                 WHERE s."last_modified"
                 LIMIT 1);

SELECT * 
FROM TABLE(INFER_SCHEMA(LOCATION => @mystage/path1,
                        FILES    => $file_name)
           );
```